# Transferring django settings to Environment Variables

Tags: django, ubuntu, django-settings, daphne

I set the django project settings and added values to environment variables at my local ubuntu mashine and AWS Ubuntu server using `.bashrc` file at the root folder.

```
...
export DEBUG="True"
...
```

**settings.py**

```
...
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG', False)
...
```

At local all working good, but at production server values are not importing. Why doesn't it work on both machines? How do I set up production?

Im running production server using asgi server daphne, accordingly this  [tutorial](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html)

**upd**

**asgi.py**

```
import os
import django
from channels.routing import get_default_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
django.setup()
application = get_default_application()
```

Comment: What you should do is set a `.env` file with those values and push that to AWS. And remember to put it on `.gitignore`

Comment: what do you mean by "server values are not importing"? Do you use `os.environ['DEBUG']` to import it in your settings? Do you get an error? Are the values wrong? Also, how do you run your production django? gunicorn? uWSGI? Which user is defined in the gunicorn process?

Comment: @HigorRossato I created `.env` file at the same folder with settings.py , added values and reboot server, but nothing

Comment: @dirkgroten I've completed the question. I got an SECRET_KEY error. I run production using asgi server daphne

Comment: but you haven't told us how you run django on your production server

Comment: @dirkgroten wrote in the previous comment and completed the question

Comment: Can you try `echo $SECRET_KEY` on terminal to check if env var is indeed available?

Comment: @AniketSinha yes, returning right values

Comment: Env variables are present but not passed to your server. I've encountered this while using apache2/wsgi server. I solved it by adding vars to `/etc/apache2/envvars`. Is there something similar in asgi? Can you show content of `asgi.py`?

Comment: @AniketSinha  the question has been updated

Answer (score 2):

So, what I usually do is: I have a script which runs when Django is setup and creates a `.env` file with some values.

**project_setup.py**

```py
import os
import random
import string


def write_dot_env_file(env_file):
    settings = get_settings()
    with open(env_file, 'w') as f:
        for k, v in settings.items():
            f.write(f'{k.upper()}={v}\n')


def get_settings():
    return {
        'SECRET_KEY': generate_secret_key(),
        'DEBUG': True,
        'ALLOWED_HOSTS': '*',
    }


def generate_secret_key():
    specials = '!@#$%^&*(-_=+)'
    chars = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + specials
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(50))


def main():
    env_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '.env')

    if not os.path.isfile(env_file):
        write_dot_env_file(env_file)
    else:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then on my `manage.py` and `wsgi.py` just before Django setting the path of the settings you do:

**manage.py**

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
from project_setup import main as project_setup_main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    project_setup_main()
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'yoursettings')
    ...
```

And that's it. When Django runs it'll create a `.env` file for you with the minimum requirements. Or you can just create the function `generate_secret_key` inside your `settings.py` and use it as a default for your `SECRET_KEY` declaration, like: `SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', get_secret_key())`

Comment: Higor, thanks for your advice, but adding a .env file doesn't work in my case. I tried to add it to the root of the project and to the folder with manage.py and to the folder with settings.py and asgi.py.

Comment: Why it doesn't work? Technically it should work and you placed in the correct place, in the root of your project.

Comment: Well, you have to source the `.env` file somewhere too, no?  You could modify `project_setup_main` to also set the environ if it isn't already set...